# UnityWebRequest / UnityEngine.WWW — FileNotFoundException when loading class from Json

Tags: unity

I'm trying to load a class using `JsonUtility` to populate a few strings. I navigate to the file using [Unity Simple File Browser](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnitySimpleFileBrowser) and load it using the following coroutine:

```
IEnumerator ShowLoad()
{
    yield return FileBrowser.WaitForLoadDialog(FileBrowser.PickMode.Files, false, null, null, "Upload", "Select");


    if (FileBrowser.Success)
    {
        Debug.Log("File Browsed: " + FileBrowser.Result[0]);

        UnityWebRequest url = new UnityWebRequest("file:///" + FileBrowser.Result[0]);

        yield return url;

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(url.ToString());
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Campaign c = JsonUtility.FromJson<Campaign>(json);
        CampaignName = c.CampaignName;
        saveFolder = c.saveFolder;
        savePath = c.savePath;
        persistentFolder = c.persistentFolder;
        persistentPath = c.persistentPath;
    }
}
```

But every time I try to run the code I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "C:\Users\arily\Documents\GitKraken\DND-Astra\Astra\UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest"
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) (at <7b935204f5ff4bcab44b3b0ebca330bf>:0)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options) (at <7b935204f5ff4bcab44b3b0ebca330bf>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions)
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, System.Int32 bufferSize) (at <7b935204f5ff4bcab44b3b0ebca330bf>:0)
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks) (at <7b935204f5ff4bcab44b3b0ebca330bf>:0)
System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path) (at <7b935204f5ff4bcab44b3b0ebca330bf>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(string)
Campaign+<ShowLoad>d__12.MoveNext () (at Assets/Campaign.cs:90)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <ab7de6937a4448b0a6ccd59e9820599a>:0)
```

I have tried the same method using `WWW` to load an image and it worked, but when loading a JSON using `WWW` I get the same error referring to `UnityEngine.WWW` instead. I haven't been able to find anything online about it, so I'm posting here. Any insight or tips would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this a long time ago and forgot to post my solution here. I think UnityWebRequest was the problem, so I used SerializationUtility instead.

```html
public IEnumerator ShowLoad()
    {
        yield return FileBrowser.WaitForLoadDialog(FileBrowser.PickMode.Files, false, null, null, "Upload", "Select");


        if (FileBrowser.Success)
        {
            Debug.Log("File Browsed: " + FileBrowser.Result[0].ToString());

            using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileBrowser.Result[0]);
            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

            var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            Campaign c = SerializationUtility.DeserializeValue<Campaign>(bytes, DataFormat.JSON);

            yield return c;

            CampaignName = c.CampaignName;

            savedCrafts = new List<CraftingRecipe>(c.savedCrafts);
            foreach (CraftingRecipe recipe in savedCrafts)
            {
                recipe.loaded = true;
            }

            TimeManager.SetTime(c.campaignMonth, c.campaignDay, c.campaignYear, c.campaignHour);

            SetPaths();

            Debug.Log("Campaign Loaded: " + CampaignName);

            PlayerManager.Manager.CmdSendCampaign(json);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your resultant path is wrong:

`"C:\Users\arily\Documents\GitKraken\DND-Astra\Astra\UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest"`

Surely that should be something more like,

`"C:\Users\arily\Documents\GitKraken\DND-Astra\Astra\myfile.json"`

I think you've got this part wrong:

`FileBrowser.Result[0]`

Should probably be something like `FileBrowser.Result[0].fileName` as its currently converting an `object` to a `string` representation.

Comment: Rather than that, Arilyn is also making a `new UnityWebRequest` of a local file. That seems kinda wrong too. According to the github, `FileBrowserHelpers.ReadBytesFromFile( FileBrowser.Result[0] )` returns a byte[]

Comment: That's what I thought - was going to suggest running a webserver - but the solution should fit the problem, rather than vice-versa.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. The `Debug.Log` statement outputs the correct path. The result isn't the issue, I don't think, since using the `.ToString` method didn't change anything. Line 90 is referred to in the error which ends up being `StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(url.ToString());`

Comment: You dont want to use UnityWebRequest if you want to load a local file

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it by using `System.IO` and replacing the entire url with a json reference directly reading the file. `string json = File.ReadAllText(@FileBrowser.Result[0].ToString());`  Not sure why so many examples suggested using `WWW`

Comment: @Arilyn want to post your solution as an Answer below?